# Injective resolution of complexes equivalent to regular definition

Tags: homological-algebra

Let **A** be an abelian category and let $A \in $ **A**. Denote by Inj**A** the category of injective objects of **A**. We denote by $A\langle0\rangle$ the complex concentrated in degree zero. I define an injective resolution to be a complex $B$ in Inj**A** quasi-isomorphic to $A\langle0\rangle$.

Question. Is this equivalent to the regular definition or do I need to specify that $B^i = 0$ for $i<0$? If this is obvious, I apologise. I am tired right now.

Comment: Unless your definition of "complex" excludes negative degrees, this is an extra condition in general.

Comment: Are you the same aaron as [aaron](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/191002/aaron) ? I mean, with "Is the cokernel of the pullback-pushforward of a coherent sheaf in the image of the pushforward on the complement" ?